# I'm not able to get my view inside my CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, sinch, videocall

Here I'm adding two different view in two different layout

1. For Remote Video
2. For Local Video
   But addview for local video doesn't fit under cardview as defined in xml file

When I tried to reduce the size of remote view to half of my screen like the image below the local video fits under cardview perfectly but when my remote view as match parent it disturbs my local video in cardview

Picture 1. When Remote Video as Match Parent
[image: When Remote Video as Match Parent]

Picture 2. When Remote Video Size Decreased
[image: When Remote Video Size Decreased]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/remoteVideo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vdo_top_back">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/remoteUser"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Ayush"
            android:textColor="#1E1E1E"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:textSize="28sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Ringing"
            android:textColor="#1E1E1E"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/callDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textColor="#1E1E1E"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/localVideo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>




    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_nav_back"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/callend_back"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/hangupButton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_call_end_24"/>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/hangupButton">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_volume_up_24"/>
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_videocam_off_24"/>
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_mic_off_24"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

```
remoteview.addView(rview)
localView.addView(lview)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the remote video view exactly?  I wonder if this is a bad interaction between clipping and however the video is rendered...

Comment: Okay Remote View is my Relative layout where i add my remote Video which i receive when someone picks a call and add this remote video as addView() to remote view

Comment: What type of View, exactly, is the remote video?  e.g., VideoView, SurfaceView, etc.

Comment: It is VideoView Type

Comment: It might be due to how `SurfaceView` (which VideoView is a subclass of) [renders its content](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView).  I'm not sure if it's possible in your case, but switching to a TextureView instead might make it work.  It's potentially also worth [filing a bug](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs) if you can make a minimal reproducible example project.